# using statement cannot find namespace in bin directory DLL

Tags: c#, namespaces, bin

I have a using statement in a project and the project target framework is 2.0,

using SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses;

Also I have  bin directory under the project root folder with the following

SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses.NET20.dll

Visual studio does not compile. Please help. Thanks so much!

Shu

Comment: Just having the DLL in a folder doesn't do anything automatically. Does your project include a reference to the DLL?

Comment: [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Reference Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx)

Comment: Why do you think “Visual studio does not compile”? Is it, perhaps, showing an error message? Read it. Add the message to your question.